# Trouble loading MXNetLink in console mode

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, librarylink

I'm using v11.1 on ubuntu, any ideas what is wrong here:

```
In[3]:= << MXNetLink`
```

> ```
> $MXNetLinkLib::loadfail:
>    Failed to load MXNetLink library at
>     /home/mma/SystemFiles/Components/MXNetLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/MXNetLink.so.
>
> InitialiazeSymbols::notloaded: Cannot initialize symbols if libraries aren't loaded.
>
> CreateManagedLibraryExpression::nrname:
>    The name NDArray is not registered as a library expression manager.
>
> LibraryFunction::libload:
>    The function WL_NDArrayCreateEx was not loaded from the file
>     /home/mma/SystemFiles/Components/MXNetLink/LibraryResources/Linux-x86-64/MXNetLink.so.
>
> General::interr: An internal error occurred. Please contact Wolfram Research.
> ```

Comment: Loads fine in 11.0.1 on Win 8.1 Pro and confirmed with ``?MXNetLink`*``. Don't have 11.1 on this machine so can't verify at the moment.

Comment: Is this because you install Mathematica without root?

Comment: I just confirmed that this works without any errors on 11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit). I did not have root access.

Comment: Since the problem was due to insufficient permissions, it would have been nice if $MXNetLinkLib::loadfail printed the corresponding error code (EPERM) for this failure, helping the user diagnose the root cause effectively.

Comment: @dan7geo I agree that root is not necessary to run Mathematica, but did you install Mathematica to your home directory without root?

Comment: @xslittlegrass Yes, I did.

Comment: Seems to work on Ubuntu 17.04, M11.1.1.  No root access.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no one can reproduce the problem and the OP did not respond to comments (essentially: can't be answered without more information).

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for not responding, I was out on vacation!